# Unexpected with Boolean when data dumper JSON

Tags: json, perl, data-dumper

My perl code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

if ( not -f "$ARGV[0]" ) { die "$!"; }

open(DATA,"$ARGV[0]") || die "$!";
$data = <DATA>;
close(DATA);

use JSON qw(decode_json);
$tidy = decode_json($data);

use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;
#$Data::Dumper::Indent = 1;
$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1;

print Dumper $tidy;
```

My JSON data:

```
[{"n":"v8_skillgames","i":"m1QhFLZ2CI","s":21254,"t":1522783462114739392,"m":false},{"n":"v8_breakaway","i":"kpOIPLacEa","s":6163,"t":1522783462115880128,"m":false}]
```

Unexpected Output:

```
[
  {
    'i' => 'm1QhFLZ2CI',
    'm' => bless( do{\(my $o = 0)}, 'JSON::PP::Boolean' ),
    'n' => 'v8_skillgames',
    's' => 21254,
    't' => '1522783462114739392'
  },
  {
    'i' => 'kpOIPLacEa',
    'm' => $VAR1->[0]{'m'},
    'n' => 'v8_breakaway',
    's' => 6163,
    't' => '1522783462115880128'
  }
]
```

I write some perl script to parse a single line JSON data.
But I got unexpected output about 'm'. What's wrong?

Comment: It's simply a boolean value. You should have no problem using it like any other hash element value, ignoring the fact that it's actually an object.

Answer (score 1):

I search around google and found the solution:

```
use JSON::PP qw(decode_json);
$JSON::PP::true  = 'true';
$JSON::PP::false = 'false';
```

Comment: 1. These variables are not documented, so it could be changed in the future. 2. Why would you want to load booleans as strings?

Comment: I just want to dump data correctly.  Something like JSON Viewer.